# How to push a particular file to git repository, while the local commit is not in sync with remote repository

Tags: git

I was trying to push a file from my local git repository to central git repository. As my local repository is not in sync with central remote repository, I am unable to push the file. My code requirement is that I can't 'git pull' the repository. I need to do a 'git push' on only one file, without doing a 'git pull'. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to `git pull`: where do this requirement comes from? Also, what do you mean by "`git push` only one file" (with you push commits, not files)

Answer (score 0):

Your code "requirement" is off-kilter.  If you are behind the remote repository, you should be doing a `git pull` to sync up before attempting to push your local branch.  Your options are:

```
git pull origin yourBranch
```

or

```
git pull --rebase origin yourBranch
```

The first option will update your remote tracking branch `origin/yourBranch` with whatever is on the remote and attempt to merge it into your local branch.  The second option will also update the remote tracking branch, but will instead *rebase* your local branch on the remote.